# Checkbox ng-model value not changing / updating as per checkbox click

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, checkbox

I have below checkbox :-

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleShowOtherUserConfiguration()"
       ng-model="showOtherUserConfiguration" 
       name="ShowOtherUserConfiguration"
       value="showOtherUserConfiguration" />
```

in app.controller I have set :-

```
$scope.showOtherUserConfiguration = false;
```

So that checkbox will always remain `false` when page is loaded.

But what happening is :-

Checkbox is remaining unchecked when page is loading , at that time , `$scope.showOtherUserConfiguration` value is `false`.

When checkbox is checked , its value remains `false`.

When Checkbox status is changed from checked to unchecked ,
`$scope.showOtherUserConfiguration` value becomes `true`.

Please guide me how can `$scope.showOtherUserConfiguration` remain `false` when unchecked and `true` when checked ?

Note :- Not changing anything within `toggleShowOtherUserConfiguration()` function other than alterting `$scope.showOtherUserConfiguration` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `ng-click` with checkbox you need to use `ng-change` for checkbox events.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
 <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('app', []);
      app.controller('OneController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.showOtherUserConfiguration = false;
        $scope.toggleShowOtherUserConfiguration = function (argument) {
            console.log($scope.showOtherUserConfiguration);
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="OneController">
    <input type="checkbox"
           ng-change="toggleShowOtherUserConfiguration()"
           ng-model="showOtherUserConfiguration"
           name="ShowOtherUserConfiguration"
           value="showOtherUserConfiguration" />
    {{showOtherUserConfiguration}}
</body>
</html>
```